# JAR runs using java -jar command but not on double-click

Tags: java, jar, double-click

I wrote this program in stack.java file. class 'stack' implements a stack and class 'test' tests it:

```
class stack
{
  int top;
  int s[]=new int [5];

  public stack()
  {
    top=-1;
  }

  public void push(int a)
  {
    if(top==4)
      System.out.println("Stack already full.");
    else
    {
      top++;
      s[top]=a;
      System.out.println("Element "+a+" Pushed.");
    }   
  }

  public int pop()
  {
    if(top==-1)
    {
      System.out.print("Stack already empty. ");
      return 0;
    }  
    else
      return(s[top--]);  
  }

  public void display()
  {
    for(int i=0;i<=top;i++)
      System.out.print(s[i]+"  ");
    System.out.print("\n");
  }
}

class test
{
  public static void main(String a[])
  {
    stack obj=new stack();
    obj.push(1);
    obj.push(2);
    obj.push(3);
    obj.push(4);
    obj.push(5);
    obj.push(6);
    System.out.println("\nStack:");
    obj.display();
    System.out.println("\nRemoving Element: "+(obj.pop()));
    System.out.println("Removing Element: "+(obj.pop()));
    System.out.println("Removing Element: "+(obj.pop()));
    System.out.println("Removing Element: "+(obj.pop()));
    System.out.println("Removing Element: "+(obj.pop()));
    System.out.println("Removing Element: "+(obj.pop()));
  }
}
```

I compiled this using command: `javac stack.java`
The files 'stack.class' and 'test.class' were created. Now I created the executable using command:

```
jar cvfe abc.jar test test.class stack.class
```

The jar works perfectly using command: `java -jar abc.jar` but on double clicking the jar file nothing happens.
I can't figure out the problem. Please help.......

Comment: I suppose this is more of an OS issue than java. Could you supply the OS?

Comment: OS: Windows 7 Ultimate. Other jar files are working perfectly...

Answer (score 1):

Probably you miss the manifest file or in the manifest file is not specified the entry point class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

Comment: The option e in jar command added the manifest file. It contains:Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: test

Comment: Yes, you're right, what I meant was to check if it actually inside the jar file was the poster properly configured, in case with problems with packages.

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to create `.bat` file on Windows with: `java -jar abc.jar`, then double click on it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to create batch file if you want to execute the same with double click

> steps to create .bat file
>   1. open notepad,2. write java -cp abc.jar packagename.classname or java -jar abc.jar 3. save the notepad file as execute_abc.bat 4.double click execute_abc.bat file